# Can't populate PeoplePicker, SpClientPeoplePickerDict is undefined

Tags: 2013, people-picker

I'm trying to populate a PeoplePicker field, using this code:

```
function testPeoplePicker(){

var ppDiv=$("div[title='PP Field Name']");
var ppEditor=ppDiv.find("[title='PP Field Name']");
var spPPD=SPClientPeoplePicker.SpClientPeoplePickerDict;
console.log(typeof spPPD === "undefined");
var spPP=spPPD[ppDiv[0].id];
ppEditor.val("Lastname, Firstname");
spPP.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);

}

SP.SOD.executeFunc("/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js","SP.ClientContext",function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            testPeoplePicker();
        },2000);
});
```

However, the `typeof spPPD === "undefined"` check returns true, indicating that the PeoplePicker dictionary is undefined, and the `spPPD[ppDiv[0].id]` lookup gives this error:

```
Unable to get property 
'PPFieldName_0e1071d1-0f13-47dd-957f-1cab4c98c3f2_$ClientPeoplePicker' 
of undefined or null reference
```

Any idea why I can't access the People Picker dictionary?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the people picker javascript library is loaded. Please try this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function () {
                //your code goes here
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Variable "PeoplePicker" was undefined and I was receiving  error

`SPClientPeoplePicker is not defined`.

For future readers working sample

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           SP.SOD.executeFunc("/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js","SP.ClientContext",function(){
           setTimeout(function(){
           test();
           },2000);
        });


function test(){

            var dispTitle = "People picker title";         
            var pickerDiv = $("[id^='PeoplePickerInternalName'][title='" + dispTitle + "']");


            var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv[0].id];
            peoplePicker.OnUserResolvedClientScript = function GetData(pickerDiv) {

               $("input[id^='field1']").val(peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo()[0].EntityData.Email);
               $("input[id^='field2']").val(peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo()[0].DisplayText);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Why the two second delay? That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: He's responding to the initial message, which had the two second delay.