# SharePoint Online permissions required to run a jquery script that removes resolved user on edit form

Tags: permissions, user, delete, online, clientpeoplepicker

I have a jquery script placed on a list edit form that removes resolved user from a people picker field. But the problem I am having is, it works for certain users and it doesn't for others. I tried with different groups changing custom permission levels to no avail. Anyone with ideas is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the script that removes the user, is it removing the "current" user from the field if present upon entering edit mode?

Comment: I used a pretty much standard function that's out there... SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];
    var AllResolvedUsers=spPeoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    AllResolvedUsers.forEach(function (index) {
    spPeoplePicker.DeleteProcessedUser(AllResolvedUsers[index]);
    });
 document.getElementById(spPeoplePicker.InitialHelpTextElementId).style.display = 'inline';
}

Comment: Are you sure it's a permission issue? Have you checked the console/network tab for a user that's experiencing issues? It might be related to scripts loading out of order, refer here for what I mean: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166753/cant-populate-peoplepicker-spclientpeoplepickerdict-is-undefined

Comment: Thanks for you reply Chad, I figured it out and yeah it was a permissions issue on where the jquery-ui was referenced. some of the people in the group had access to that site collection where the jquery-ui resides and some didn't. That was the reason.